# Можно ли указать путь к файлу в самой консоли?

Tags: c++

В задании указано, что можно использовать графический интерфейс. Само задание:

...
Заполнение стека:
a) с консоли.
b) из файла (выбор файла, тек. папка, любая папка).
...

У меня консольное приложение (Win 7). Можно ли как-то указать (написать например) путь к файлу в консоли, который надо открыть или это только для графического интерфейса? И если можно, то как?

Comment: Вы когда-нибудь программу с параметрами командной строки запускали?

Comment: Да, запускал. Но тут выбор в самой программе, когда она уже запущена.

Comment: А, вот вы о чём! Ну да, можно ввести например имя файла, в чём проблема? `cout >> "Enter filename: "; cin << filename;`.

Comment: В задании сказано выбор папки. Что-то типа "введите путь" и пишешь C:\Users\Name\Desktop\name.txt Такое вообще возможно реализовать в консоли?

Comment: Это именно то, о чем и сказал VladD.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

 string filename;
 ifstream fin(filename);
 cout << "Введите имя файла: ";
 cin >> filename;

 if (!fin.is_open())
 {
  cout << "\nФайл '" << filename << "' не может быть открыт!\n";
 }
 else
 {
  for (string line; getline(fin, line);)
  {
   cout << line << endl;
  }
 }

 cout << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}`

@VladD в чём ошибка?

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Не знаю, а как она проявляется? Компилируется? Падает в процессе выполнения? Делает не то?

Comment: @VladD срабатывает `if (!fin.is_open())`

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Так, это уже интереснее. Попробуйте для отладки вывести, чему равно `filename` после `cin`. (Или посмотрите в отладчике, так же проще!)

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Ээээ! Стойте! Вы же **сначала** открываете файл по пустому имени, а только **потом** вводите это имя с клавиатуры! Сделайте наоборот.

Comment: Надо больше спать. Да действительно глупая ошибка. Спасибо @VladD

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Пожалуйста! Вот и хорошо, разобрались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");

    string filename;
    cout << "Введите имя файла: ";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream fin(filename);

    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "\nФайл '" << filename << "' не может быть открыт!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (string line; getline(fin, line);)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```